# How to work around partial specialization of function template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

For example, I have a class:

```
class A
{
    enum {N = 5};
    double mVariable;

    template<class T, int i>
    void f(T& t)
    {
        g(mVariable); // call some function using mVariable.
        f<T, i+1>(t); // go to next loop
    }

    template<class T>
    void f<T, N>(T& t)
    {} // stop loop when hit N.
};
```

Partial specialization is not allowed in function template. How do I work around it in my case?

I slightly changed the example of Arne Mertz, like:

```
template<int n>
struct A
{
    enum {N = n};
    ...
};
```

and use A like:

```
A<5> a;
```

The I cannot compile on Visual Studio 2012. Is it a compiler bug or something else? It is quite strange.

**EDIT:** Checked. It is a Visual Studio bug. :(

I think Nim gives the most simple way to implement it.

Comment: Any reason you are not using a `for` loop ?

Comment: I [tried the templated version on gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5788126f080ae192) and it compiles well. You can even leave the enum completely and make `N` itself the template parameter.

Comment: What is the point of using the formal parameter `t`?

Comment: @Constructor It is of type template parameter T. For example, you can write A's contents to variable t of different types.

Comment: @user1899020 Where it is used?

Comment: @Constructor It depends on cases.

Comment: @user1899020 I mean in what function it is used? In `f` (or its specialization) or in `g`? In your current code it is not necessary to use this parameter.

Comment: @Constructor It is a short simple version of code. The point is on how to work around partial specialization of function templates, not what code try to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With c++11 support, you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    enum {N = 5};
    double mVariable;

    void g(int i, double v)
    { std::cout << i << "  " << v << std::endl; }

    template<int i, class T>
    typename enable_if<i >= N>::type f(T& t)
    {} // stop loop when hit N.

    template<int i, class T>
    typename enable_if<i < N>::type f(T& t)
    {
        g(i, mVariable); // call some function using mVariable.
        f<i+1, T>(t); // go to next loop
    }

};

int main(void)
{
    A a;
    int v = 0;
    a.f<0>(v);
}
```

Main reason I like is that you don't need any of the cruft as required by the previous answers...

Comment: Just wanted to add that techincally you don't need C++ 11 for this. enable_if is a class that can be implemented in any C++ version using SFINAE.

Comment: Of course in real life the definition of `struct A` is probably in a header file, so you certainly would not type '`using namespace std;`' before the struct, and would just spell out `std::enable_if`.

Comment: Caveat: Looks like while I've been away several folks have modified my original code. There was a *reason* I used the aliases, it makes the whiole meta programming side of things a lot easier...

Comment: @Nim it makes it easier to type but not so easy to read for people who don't know the stuff yet.

Answer (score 7):

The most straight forward solution is to use a template class instead of a function:

```
class A
{
    enum {N = 5};
    double mVariable;

    template <class T, int i>
    struct fImpl {
      static_assert(i<N, "i must be equal to or less than N!");
      static void call(T& t, A& a) {
        g(a.mVariable);
        fImpl<T, i+1>::call(t, a);
      }
    };

    template<class T>
    struct fImpl<T,N> {
      static void call(T&, A&)  {} // stop loop when hit N.
    };

 public:

    template<class T, int i>
    void f(T& t)
    {
        fImpl<T, i>::call(t,*this);
    }

};
```

[Example link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf81ada41882eeab)

Comment: Should not the first call of `fImpl::call`, in `f`, be indexed by `i` ?

Comment: +1 but just a nitpick: if `A` is itself a class template, one can run into difficulties with specializing nested templates (depending on partial vs full specialization). So in that case it is better to move that stuff into a `detail` namespace.

Comment: @TemplateRex yes, but in that case `fImpl` must either be made a friend of all instantiations of `A` or a handle to the needed internals of `A` (in this case, of `mVariable`) has to be passed around. Moving both `fImpl` and `mVariable` into a nontemplated base class should be considered as well.

Comment: This method is straightforward. I slightly modified your example as above. I got compilation error. Would you please take a look at it? Thanks. I checked it with other compilor. It is a Visual Studio bug.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a helper class:

```
template <int i, int M>
struct inc_up_to
{
  static const int value = i + 1;
};

template <int i>
struct inc_up_to<i, i>
{
  static const int value = i;
};


template<class T, int i>
void f(T& t)
{
    if (i < N) {
        g(mVariable); // call some function using mVariable.
        f<T, inc_up_to<i, N>::value>(t);
    }
}
```

It stops the compile-time recursion by making `f<T, N>` refer to `f<T, N>`, but that call is avoided by the run-time condition, breaking the loop.

A simplified and more robust version of the helper (thanks @ArneMertz) is also possible:

```
template <int i, int M>
struct inc_up_to
{
  static const int value = (i >= M ? M : i + 1); // this caps at M
  // or this:
  static const int value = (i >= M ? i : i + 1); // this leaves i >= M unaffected
};
```

This doesn't even need the partial specialisation.

Comment: you could simplify the thing *and* catch the `i>N` issue all our implementations have by defining only the common case with `value = (M>=N) ? i : i+1` and completely leaving out the specialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate partial specialization of function template with function overloading:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A
{
    enum {N = 5};
    double mVariable;

    // ...

    void g(double)
    {
        // ...
    }

public:

    template<class T, int i = 0>
    void f(T& t, std::integral_constant<int, i> = std::integral_constant<int, i>())
    {
        g(mVariable);
        f(t, std::integral_constant<int, i + 1>());
    }

    template<class T>
    void f(T& t, std::integral_constant<int, N>)
    {
    }

};
```

Example of using:

```
A a;
int t = 0;

a.f(t);
a.f(t, std::integral_constant<int, 2>()); // if you want to start loop from 2, not from 0
```

It is a C++11 solution, however (not so much because of `std::integral_constant` class, but because of default template parameter of function template). It can be made shorter using some additional C++11 features:

```
template<int i>
using integer = std::integral_constant<int, i>;

template<class T, int i = 0>
void f(T& t, integer<i> = {})
{
    g(mVariable);
    f(t, integer<i + 1>());
}

template<class T>
void f(T& t, integer<N>)
{
}
```